# Confusion about auto margins with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

[MDN suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left#auto) that `margin-left: auto` with `position: absolute` will set the left margin to 0, but that does not seem to be the case in practice. I am now wondering if it is a bug in the browser, or in the MDN documentation as my example seems to align to the right.

> fixed or absolute 
> 0, except if both margin-left and margin-right are set to auto.

This example has `margin-left` set to `auto` and `margin-right` unspecified (i.e. initial value of 0) and the left margin appears to be computed as taking the remaining space rather than 0 as suggested by the source above: https://jsfiddle.net/40txneL7

I have also found [a snippet in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abspos-margins) suggesting that the remaining space is divided between the `auto` margins, and not set to 0 if just one axis margin is set.

Is MDN documentation incorrect here, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of rules concerning the width and the placement of the position absolute that you can read about here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abs-non-replaced-width

> The constraint that determines the used values for these elements is:
>
> `left + margin-left + border-left-width + padding-left + width + padding-right + border-right-width + margin-right + right = width of containing block`

We don't have padding and the following rule apply:

> If none of the three is auto: ... If one of `margin-left` or `margin-right` is auto, solve the equation for that value. If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for left

So you will have

`0px(left) + margin-left + 200px(width) + 0px(margin-right not specfied) + 0px(right) = width of containing block`

The containing block in your case is the viewport so we have 100% of screen width. If we solve the equation you will get

`margin-left = viewport width - 200px`

so not equal to 0. You can verify this by checking the Dev tool

[image]

We set 0 for margin for the other cases. If you continue reading the Spec you can find:

> Otherwise, set auto values for `margin-left` and `margin-right` to 0, and pick one of the following six rules that apply.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - that constraint equation makes a lot of sense. This suggests that MDN isn't accurate to say the computed value is `0, except if both margin-left and margin-right are set to auto.`, is that correct?

Comment: @GEsmond The MDN try to simplify things and sometimes this can create some inaccuracy especially if we dig into specific cases like this. The MDN is a good resource to understand things in general but if you really want to get very accurate detail for each case you need to refer to the Spec

Answer (score -1):

The current position of your absolutely positioned element is not due to `margin-left: auto` as you assume but to `right: 0` since it overrides the `left: 0` property.

Just remove `right: 0` and you will see that your element is positioned left ignoring the margin-property.

Comment: I believe that this is incorrect. Do you have a source to suggest that `right` overrides `left`? The spec says the reverse - that `left` takes precedence in LTR mode. MDN also agrees that `left` overrides in this manner. I used the inset properties to increase the containing block. You can inspect the element to see the effect that the margin has.

Comment: @GEsmond I seem to have misunderstood the question. I didn't mean that right overwrites left in the technical sense, but the frontend output if you know what I mean. i thought it was just about the position of your element and didn't know that this is a general web theory question